# Problem with processing POST form request in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a to-do list web application using Flask. But when I made a handler for the to-do creation form, the data isn't written to the database

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todos.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

@app.route('/' , methods=['post', 'get'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'post':
        todo_title = request.form['title']

        db.session.add(Todo(title=todo_title))
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')

app.run()
```

```html
<form method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Todo</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is specifically causing your problem, but the methods that you specified: `post` and `get`, should be capitalized. eg. POST, GET

Answer (score 0):

Capitalise `post` in `if` condition and add `db.create_all()` to create your table.